# Finding the path of my documents folder in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, titanium-mobile

```
file://localhost/var/mobile/Application/EAC0BC34-6A82-41CB-AE44-9CD8E7D880C8/Documents
```

I get an alert this is my path, but i am unable to find where this location is all about. I am using iOS 5.0 to deploy my Application in ma device.

Thanks

Comment: I hope you have doubled all the '/' in your path if your path is correct and you write it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Or as per your tag, maybe you're using Titanium? If so maybe this helps:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Filesystem+Access+and+Storage - `Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory`