# How to Impliment Browse functionality in ios

Tags: ios, ipad, file-upload, browser

I want to Implement Browse functionality in my Ipad App.
Actually My requirement is,When i chick on button need to open the all document are existed in device same like as "widows my computer".After Browsing that document,Select any document and  I need to Upload the selected document to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have access to the "sandbox" of your application. It is by default an empty folder. It is called the application documents folder (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915951/427083) how to get it). Unfortunately, unless you have a jailbroken phone, you have (mostly) no access to other folders.

If you populate this folder with files you can certainly show them in your UI and send them to a server.

Comment: So,is it not possible to implement browse concept in ios device?In that time how to select any document and upload to server?Please guide me.

Comment: Study the methods of `NSFileManager`. You can get arrays of file names etc. Populate a table view with this information. Implement a file upload via `NSURLConnection`. It's all really quite straight forward. Don't hesitate to ask SOF again for any sub-questions.